# Single Sign On with Linux systems and with OSX

Tags: mac-os-x, sso, linux

When rolling out SharePoint in an organization using Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) systems as well as Mac OSX - how to implement Single-Sign-On? Of course the SharePoint is on the main Active Directory domain.

On the Windows boxes everyone is logged into the domain and due to the SharePoint being in the Intranet zone (or configured in about:config [Firefox]), the user never sees a Login box.

How to do SSO in OSX as well as Linux in a primarily Active Directory / Microsoft based company? I have heard from users that they constantly have to login again (e.g. on the search site looking for users, the user images are pulled from the mysite - hence cross domain: search.company.com and my.company.com).